# Throwing an exception vs Mono.error() in Spring webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I'm working on a Spring webflux project and I want to understand the difference between **throwing an exception** vs using **Mono.error()**.

If there is a validation class like this for example:

```
 public class NameValidator {

   public static boolean isValid(String name) {
     if(StringUtils.isEmpty(name)) {throw new RuntimeException("Invalid name");}
     return true;
  }
}



public class NameValidator2 {

   public static Mono<Object> isValid(String name) {
     if(StringUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
          return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Invalid name"));}
     return Mono.just(true);

  }

 }
```

What are the pros & cons with each approach. When to use one over the other while working with reactive streams using spring webflux?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As @Joao already stated, the recommended way to deal with an error is to call the `error` method on a `Publisher`(`Mono.error`/`Flux.error`).

I would like to show you an example in which the traditional `throw` does not work as you may expect:

```
public void testErrorHandling() {
    Flux.just("a", "b", "c")
        .flatMap(e -> performAction()
            .onErrorResume(t -> {
                System.out.println("Error occurred");
                return Mono.empty();
            }))
        .subscribe();
}

Mono<Void> performAction() {
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

The `onErrorResume` operator will never be executed because the exception is thrown before `Mono` is assembled.

Comment: Can I say that an exception that uses `throw`  rather than `Mono.error()` will not work with any `onErrorXXX` operators?

Comment: In general, `throw` works just like  `Mono.error()` (Reactor catches your exception and transforms it into a `Mono.errror`.  The example above does not work because the exception is thrown during the assembly period before `Mono` is created.

Comment: Do you mean I can first create the pipeline and assign it to a variable and call `subscribe()` on that variable? Will that work with `throw`?

Answer (score 4):

Basically you will have the same result in the end and no difference between the two options (maybe performance wise but I have not found anything backing this opinion so I guess it can be negligible.
The only “difference” is that Mono.error follows the Reactive Streams specification and throwing an exception as is does not (read more at https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm/blob/v1.0.3/README.md#2.13). However it is not prohibited, but if you like to follow standards and specifications (I guess you do) you should consider using Mono.error.

Comment: can you please specify which point exactly states that in the specifications? Point 2.13 which appears at the end of your link does not seem to say anything about throwing `Mono.error`  instead of throwing exceptions.