# What are practical differences between throwing and returning M/ux.error() once M/ux is created?

Tags: java, project-reactor

***Note.** M/ux is my shorthand for "a `Mono` or `Flux`"*

What are the practical differences between throwing and returning `M/ux.error()` *once a `M/ux` has been assembled*? Are there any? In this minimalistic example there seem to be no difference at all

```java
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public class GenericTest {
    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    void test() {
        Mono.just(1)
                .flatMap(this::doDangerousThing)
                .subscribe();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    Mono<Integer> doDangerousThing(Integer num) {
        return Mono.error(new RuntimeException());
    }
}
```

```java
// ...

    Mono<Integer> doDangerousThing(Integer num) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53596358/23434786) is good, but doesn't specifically address my question (basically, it only says you can throw as well, it will be caught and mapped to an error signal)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69184610/23434786) shows an example when an exception thrown from a `M/ux` returning method is not caught by a chained `onErrorResume()`

```java
public void testErrorHandling() {
    Flux.just("a", "b", "c")
        .flatMap(e -> performAction()
            .onErrorResume(t -> {
                System.out.println("Error occurred");
                return Mono.empty();
            }))
        .subscribe();
}

Mono<Void> performAction() {
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

However, I'm interested in whether there are any practical differences between the two once a `M/ux` is created

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Throwing an exception vs Mono.error() in Spring webflux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69178870/throwing-an-exception-vs-mono-error-in-spring-webflux)